# Define return type IO [a] Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to return the expected type IO [a]

I tried:
Type that I want

```
fc :: [a] -> IO [a]
fc a = sequence $ map show list

> fc [1,2,3]
> [1,2,3]
```

What can I do?

Comment: Okay, now we know that you want an `IO` type. What `IO` do you want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a pure value, the way to convert to into a monadic value is with the `return` (aka `pure`) function:

```
fc :: [a] -> IO [a]
fc list = return list
```

But if you want to map the `show` function over your list, the result will be `[String]`, because the function `show :: a -> String` turns any value into a `String`, so:

```
fc :: Show a => [a] -> IO [String]
fc list = return $ map show list
```

Notice the `Show a` constraint. It tells the compiler that the type `a`, whatever it is, must support function `show`. Without it, such function won't type check.

The `sequence` function is beside the point completely, since it turns a list of monadic values into one monadic value that is a list. If you wanted to use that function, then the list you pass to it must be a list of monadic values, for example:

```
fc :: Show a => [a] -> IO [()]
fc list = sequence $ map print list
```

Here, `print` is an `IO ()` action that prints out a value.

If you want a more precise answer, you'd need to specify more clearly what you're trying to do.